# Prove that if $f\left( \dfrac{x + y}{x - y} \right) = \dfrac{f(x) + y}{f(x) - y}$ then $f(-x) = -f(x)$

Tags: functions

I want to solve this problem.

Prove that if $f\left( \dfrac{x + y}{x - y} \right) = \dfrac{f(x) + y}{f(x) - y}$ then $f(-x) = -f(x)$

Any hint to prove this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? @masrosid

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Usually you'll get a better response (and fewer votes to close your question) if you show us what you've already tried, and explain where you got stuck. That also gives us a sense of what you know, so that we can better craft an appropriate answer to your question. Click "edit" below your question to modify it to show your work so far.

Comment: If your claim is true that we should actually have $f(x)=x$ as seen by putting $y=-x$.

Comment: Thank you. This $y=-x$ give me solution.

Answer (score 6):

If we put $y=-x$, then we get
$$ f(0) = f\left(\frac{x+(-x)}{x-(-x)} \right) = \frac{f(x)+(-x)}{f(x)-(-x)}. $$
Check that $f(0) \neq 1$ and that the equation above gives us
$$ f(x) = \frac{f(0)+1}{1-f(0)} x.$$
This implies your claim and as Kavi Rama Murthy pointed out, we get $f(x)=x$ (as $f(0)=0$).